# Nested Dictionary Creation - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary setup like this:

```
company = {'Honda': {}
 ,'Toyota':{}
 ,'Ford':{}
}
```

I have a list containing data like this:

```
years = ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3']
```

Finally, I also have a list of lists containing data like this:

```
sales = [[55,9,90],[44,22,67],[83,13,91]]
```

I am trying to achieve a final result that looks like this:

```
{'Honda': {'Year 1':55,'Year 2':9,'Year 3':90}
 ,'Toyota':{'Year 1':44,'Year 2':22,'Year 3':67}
 ,'Ford':{'Year 1':83,'Year 2':13,'Year 3':91}
}
```

I can access the sub-list if sales like this:

```
for i in sales:
    for j in i:
        #this would give me a flat list of all sales
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around constructing the final dictionary that would tie everything together.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `company` is a dictionary whereas `sales` is a list. How are you supposed to map the dictionary keys to the list indices? Recent versions of Python have dictionaries ordered according to insertion but depending on that doesn't seem to be the proper thing to do. Your input format doesn't seem to be proper for your problem

Comment: You are correct, I don't think you could guarantee the proper sales would match to company. This was a toy example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension with `zip`.

```py
res = {k : dict(zip(years, sale)) for k, sale in zip(company, sales)}
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on how you approached this problem? I am trying to turn this into for loops but I keep getting stuck.

Comment: @eclipsedlamp You can do it with a for loop like so: `res = {}` then 
`for k, sale in zip(company, sales): res[k] = dict(zip(years, sale))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to pair corresponding information together. First, zip the brand names with the values in `sales`. Next, zip `years` with a particular brand's sales numbers.

```
company = {brand: dict(zip(years, sales_nums)) 
          for brand, sales_nums in zip(["Honda", "Toyota", "Ford"], sales)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and a double for-loop to zip all 3 lists. Here you are:

```
final_dict = {}
    for i, (name, sub_dict) in enumerate(company.items()):
        for year, sale in zip(years, sales[i]):
            sub_dict[year] = sale
        final_dict[name] = sub_dict
```